# text below image bootstrape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2judX.jpg)

i try to fix it but still like this please help me to fix it 
i'm try change gid but still get the problem
please give me any idea about this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>

  <body>
  
  <div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive top" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/06/cb/33/06cb338efcf3ac37a90caad05fd356a2.jpg">
    <p style="background-color:#fff;">Example headline.</p>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive top" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/06/cb/33/06cb338efcf3ac37a90caad05fd356a2.jpg">
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive top" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/06/cb/33/06cb338efcf3ac37a90caad05fd356a2.jpg">
 
  
  </div>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: So your problem is the first div from the second row?

Comment: i can't see a problem

Comment: @Swellar i fixed it one more thing is image still bigger in small screen :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap` on `row` so all the columns have equal height, regardless if they have a headline or not

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/DTcHh/32896/)

```css
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.col-sm-4 {
 width:33.33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive top" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/06/cb/33/06cb338efcf3ac37a90caad05fd356a2.jpg">
    <p style="background-color:#fff;">Example headline.</p>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive top" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/06/cb/33/06cb338efcf3ac37a90caad05fd356a2.jpg">
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive top" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/06/cb/33/06cb338efcf3ac37a90caad05fd356a2.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive top" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/06/cb/33/06cb338efcf3ac37a90caad05fd356a2.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive top" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/06/cb/33/06cb338efcf3ac37a90caad05fd356a2.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive top" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/06/cb/33/06cb338efcf3ac37a90caad05fd356a2.jpg">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: one more thing image not going to smaller on small screen

Comment: @BoyIronHeart you want on smaller screen to keep 3 columns on one row ? edited my answer . or see here > https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/DTcHh/32896/

Comment: Hmmm i just want a someone help me with it 
i'm newbie to coding

Comment: well that's why stackoverflow exists. post here your questions. By the way, did my answer work for you ? if YES please rate/accept it. thanks :D

Comment: i really need help about web dev

Comment: so post here on stackoverflow your questions/problems and/or search the net for tutorials for how to learn web dev .

Comment: too big on pc screen ?